# Query generated by Hibernate is incorrect for JSON type

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, stored-procedures

I am using a Named Query to call a Function in Postgresql. The function takes JSON as an Input but when I pass the query to JPA it strips of 1 of the colons resulting in an incorrect query that is generated.

Here is my code

```
    query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from transfer_validate(\'{\"a\":\"100\",\"b\":\"200\"}\'::json,\'{\"a\":\"100\",\"b\":\"200\"}\'::json);");
    query.getResultList();
```

Below is how the Function is created:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION transfer_validate(_d json, _l json)
```

This is the error that is generated :

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ":"
  Position: 67
```

Below is the SQL that is generated for Postgres in Hibernate logs

```
select * from transfer_validate('{"a":"100","b":"200"}':json,'{"a":"100","b":"200"}':json);
```

You can clearly notice that ::json is replaced by :json and hence the error.

How can I correct this ?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It's not an ideal solution, but you can use this:

```
list = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from transfer_validate(?\\:\\:json,?\\:\\:json);")
        .setParameter(1, jsonString1)
        .setParameter(2, jsonString2)
        .getResultList();
```

Basically you're telling Hibernate that the colons are not to be interpreted as parameter names. Alternatively you can use the standard SQL cast `CAST(:a as json)`